# core plot help to draw two plots together

Tags: ipad, graph, core-plot, bar-chart, scatter

How to draw both bar and scatter plot together? I have created object of both in viewDidLoad and the datasource also read correctly. I add it to the same plotspace. But no use!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the example programs? Many of them show how to add multiple plots (of the same or different types) to a single graph.

What are you seeing? Does either plot show up, or neither of them?

Comment: I am trying to add one bar and one scatter plot. Bar appears but not scatter. Which example should i refer?

Comment: The Mac version of CPTestApp has two scatter plots and two bar plots in one graph, although it does use two plot spaces. The iPhone and iPad CPTestApp both have examples of doubled-up plots as well. It doesn't matter if the plots in a graph are the same or different types. The only difference is in some of the parameters used to configure them and in the fields that your datasource provides.

Answer (score 1):

Just add multiple plots to graph with graph addPlot

```
CPTScatterPlot * sPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    dataLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    sPlot.identifier = @"SomeIdentifier"

    dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor redColor];
    sPlot.dataLineStyle = dataLineStyle;
    sPlot.dataSource = self;

    greenCirclePlotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    greenCirclePlotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor redColor]];
    greenCirclePlotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0);
    sPlot.plotSymbol = greenCirclePlotSymbol;  

    [graph addPlot:sPlot];
```